# Which is better in python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have used some conditions statements in python which gives the same result. I would like to know which is better and what is the difference in performance and logic between them.

#### Case 1:

```py
if a and b and c:
    #some action
```

vs

```
if all( (a, b, c) ):
    #some action
```

#### Case 2:

```py
if a or b or c:
    #some action
```

vs

```py
if any( (a, b, c) ):
    #some action
```

#### Case 3:

```py
if not x in a:
    #some action
```

vs

```py
if x not in a:
    #some action
```

In the above cases, I would like know about the difference in performance and logic and preferred way.

Comment: Difference in what? Speed, logic, readability, ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Case 1**

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all

> **all(iterable)**
>
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or
>   if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

This means `if a and b and c:` and `if all( (a, b, c) ):` do the same thing (duh) but `all()` involves a function call and a loop, so it's bound to be a little slower, but really, just a tiny bit.

I'd say you use `if a and b and c:` if you have only a couple variables (no more than 3) to keep it readable and `all()` if you have more.

Keep in mind: readability is almost always more important than a minor performance improvement.

`all()` and `any()` can take a list comprehension as input which is really useful.

Note: `all()` is only available in Python 2.5+

---

**Case 2**

Same as case 1, really. Because it's almost the exact same function

> **any(iterable)**
>
> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If
>   the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

Note: `any()` is only available in Python 2.5+

---

**Case 3**

From http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

> Use is not operator rather than not ... is. While both expressions are functionally identical, the former is more readable and preferred.

You should use `if x not in a:` over `if not x in a:`, because the styleguide is holy

Comment: I would like to add that in the first two cases if we already have an iterable we should go with `any` or `all` because if we have individual elements there would be an extra cost in converting them to iterables.

Comment: @AnkurAnkan yes, i think i meant to imply that by saying it can take a LC as input :-)

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I like your statement "because the styleguide is holy". But my father told me one rule, which simplifies (quite complex) Czech grammar - try all the options which come first to your mind and pick the one, which sounds most natural to you. This assumes, you are native speaker, so the only thing to do is to work on becoming native Python speaker.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky *the only thing to do is to work on becoming native Python speaker* working on that ;-) in the meantime, I just like to follow the official styleguide :-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns We shall consider styleguide being speech of our mother :-).